# When are we supposed to use 'constructions' in mathematical geometery proofs?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry, proof-explanation, geometric-construction

In questions of Triangles or Circles where you are required to prove something, there are cases when the help of construction is required *(for example, proving the converse of Pythagoras theorem by the similarity of triangles)*.

My query is that

## **In what situation *(or condition)* are we supposed to use construction in geometric proofs?**

[PS: I am myself in high school so my question would be more relevant to students aspiring to become mathematicians and that could be the reason my question may sound dumb]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you find yourself in this kind of situation I think you should ask yourself two questions:

1. Do I have/Will I find a good* proof by construction?
2. Does my teacher accept a proof by construction?

If you answer both questions with 'YES' you are supposed to use construction. I know that answer sounds dumb, but that is what it's all about.

*But this is important: What is good? Good for the Reader and the writer of a proof is efficiency. If you're allowed to use Theorems like Pythagoras, Congruence of triangles, Law of cosines,... take that shortcut! A proof by construction could be very long.